# Do symbols beginning with & have a special meaning?

Tags: syntax, clojure, symbols

What do `&form` and `&env` do in this example (taken from [core.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L32))?

```
(def
  ^{:macro true
    :added "1.0"}
  let (fn* let [&form &env & decl] (cons 'let* decl)))
```

Do symbols beginning with `&...` (other than just plain `&`) have special meaning in any contexts?

Why aren't `&form` and `&env` used in the body of the `fn*` form?

Comment: Perhaps this link would be helpful. http://blog.jayfields.com/2011/02/clojure-and.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, &form and &env are special variables within a macro. The names begin with '&' to avoid name clashes with normal user-defined symbols.

The value of &form is the form of the original macro call before macro expansion.

The value of &env is a map of lexical bindings. The keys of &env are the lexically bound symbols.

[adapted from [stevenminer's comment](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/defmacro#comment_123)]